# Why is Babel using the `arguments` object for optional parameters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I've noticed a somewhat odd transpilation decision from babel, with regards to optional parameters. The following ES6 code:

```
function myFunction(x = 2, y = 3) {}
```

gets transpiled to

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : 2;
  var y = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : 3;
}
```

I soon have to hold a presentation about how much shorter and more concise the ES6 syntax is and how it would look in ES5 (via Babel usually). But for me this seems kinda forced and also much less performant. Are there reasons not to do this?:

```
function myFunction(x, y) {
  x = x === undefined ? 2 : x;
  y = y === undefined ? 3 : y;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Imagine a function where you would pass undefined as an argument. That's why the length check is needed.

Comment: @JaredSmith: If you pass `undefined` as the value for a parameter with a default, the default is used, not `undefined`.

Comment: For your presentation, I wouldn't compare ES2015 syntax with how the ES5 equivalent looks when transpiled. Instead, I would compare the ES2015 syntax with what you would actually write in ES5, which is unlikely to look much like what Babel does in many cases (look in particular at what it does with `class`). That's more informative in terms of the real benefits of the newer syntax. I thnk we can all agree that your first code block above is more concise than your last one (and many would argue clearer as well, but that's more subjective).

Comment: You are right, that' my goal mostly, but if I were to test the optional parameters in babel and someone said "no that's not true, it can be written in a shorter way" I would now know what to say.

Comment: Babel's goal is not to be terse but to be spec compliant.

Comment: Someone recently requested exactly this change as a loose option to the relevant plugin. I have made a PR for this here https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5778, making good progress. Would be interested if that is what you imagined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there reasons not to do this?

It would conflict with the specification, which says that the arity (`.length`) of the function is the number of declared parameters prior to the first parameter with a default value or the rest parameter. (This definition [starts here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-expectedargumentcount); following it through is...fun. But that's what it comes down to.)

Your `myFunction` has no declared parameters prior to the first one with a default value, and thus has `length == 0`. If it were transpiled as you suggest, it would have `length == 2` instead, which would be a spec violation.